# smtp.gmail.com changing MAIL TO property?

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

Does smpt.gmail.com change the `MAIL TO` property of an E-Mail? I sent one with these settings with ssl:

```
MAIL FROM:<someRandomNotExistingEmail@bla.com>
RCPT TO:<myRealGmail@googlemail.com>
DATA
From:<someRandomNotExistingEmail@bla.com>
To:<someOtherRandomNotExistingEmail@blabla.com>
Subject: Hello

Content of E-Mail.
.
250 2.0.0 OK - gsmtp
QUIT
```

I received the E-Mail, but instead of `<someRandomNotExistingEmail@bla.com>` the source was `<myRealGmail@googlemail.com>`, does Google change fake `MAIL FROM` Headers?

Comment: You're mixing `TO` and `FROM` in your question. Can you pls clarify?

Comment: I'm also missing the relationship with google-app-engine. Are you sending from a GAE app?